# How do you express "the person I did something to"?

Tags: grammar

I want to say:

> One person I told about XYZ said, "...".

Knowledgeably incorrect translation:

> XYZについて話した一人は「…」と言いました。

This makes it sound like they were the one telling me about XYZ. How do I write this so that it's clear that they are the one being told? The only ways I can think of makes it sound like they've had a moral offense committed against them (話された), or that they really wanted to know what I told them (話してもらった).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just add yourself at the start with が.

> 私がXYZについて話した一人は「…」と言いました

Comment: I keep on thinking that I need to put に in there somewhere (outside について), like: `私が一人にXYZについて話しました。` Does the necessity of the に particle go away because of the reordering of the sentence?

Comment: Does 一人の人 sound better than just 一人?

Comment: Another suggestion was made that `私に/からXYZについて聞いた一人` is also a possibility, a bit roundabout but has that に in there that I was obsessing over. @Darcinon In the paragraph this sentence was in I'd specified that there were a group of people and this is just one within it, but without that context 一人の人 probably would have worked better.